# Access Denied - Copy "Google Drive" folder from Boot Options Command Prompt

Tags: windows-10, command-line, google-drive

I updated my HP X2 detachable to Windows 10 creator's update and have not been able to login to my computer since. Start up repair doesn't work, it seems I'm going to have to reset the PC.

The Problem: I have some files in my google drive folder that had not sync to remote before the update. So I'm trying to copy the google drive to a thumb drive from boot options command prompt. Each time I try, I get "access denied" response.

Is there, a way I can login from the prompt so I don't get denied. Or is there any other way to recover the files ?